# bad performances on spatial indexes

Tags: mysql, indexing, spatial

I changed hosting plans recently. The database is passed of

Server type: Percona Server Server version: 5.6.40-84.0-log - Percona Server (GPL), Release 84.0, Revision 47234b3

at

Server type: MariaDB Server version: 10.3.23-MariaDB-1: 10.3.23 + maria ~ stretch-log - mariadb.org binary distribution

I have since several cases more than annoying.

Here is one:

I have been using spatial indexes on myISAM tables for years.

I manage two types of geometries; points and polygons.

For example, on the old server an automatic night task executed the following request in 3 minutes

```
INSERT INTO wnat_refresh_maille_in_use 
SELECT distinct wnat_mailles_geometries.unik
FROM wnat_gps, wnat_mailles_geometries
WHERE MBRCONTAINS(wnat_mailles_geometries.g_coordonnees_spacial, wnat_gps.p_coordonnees_spacial) AND in_use_by_lieudit=0
```

In the wnat_mailles_geometries table there are 12 million rows, the g_coordonnees_spacial column contains polygon geometries.
The wnat_gps table contains 800,000 rows and the p_coordonnees_spacial column contains points.

On the new server, the request times out at 20 minutes.

To get out of it, I modified the code in order to execute the page n times (limit 100,000 skip which is fine) in order to execute an INSERT per line of the wnat_gps table.

```
INSERT INTO wnat_refresh_maille_in_use SELECT distinct
     wnat_mailles_geometries.unik
  FROM wnat_mailles_geometries
    WHERE ST_CONTAINS(wnat_mailles_geometries.g_coordonnees_spacial, ST_GEOMFROMTEXT('".$row["asText"]."')) AND in_use_by_lieudit=0";
```

Thus, after 8 iterations on the page and 30 minutes, the wnat_refresh_maille_in_use table is correctly filled.

An idea ?

Comment: strat by removing the comma between tabkes and use Join with an on clause

Comment: does EXPLAIN output reveal a difference in the execution plan?

Comment: Which server is the slow one?

Comment: Show us the `EXPLAINs`.  What table has `in_use_by_lieudit`?  `SPATIAL` is available on newer versions (5.7 and 10.2) of InnoDB.